# Getting "$ is undefined" error after changing jQuery script loading to async

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a "$ is undefined" error on `$(document).ready()` after changing jQuery script loading to `async`.

Following is the short version of my code. It was working before I added the `async` attribute to my `<script>` tag that loads jQuery.

I did this based on the recommendation provided by Google Page Insight to improve my page's performance

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js" async></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
       //Some variable initialization 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Of course you get that, because the first script is not yet loaded when the second one gets executed … that’s what `async` _means_. You want `defer` instead – that does preserve and guarantee execution order.

Comment: Use google hosted libraries.

Comment: But will defer impact page load time in google page insight check.

Comment: why vote down? i am getting error so ask question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force your initialization code to wait until jQuery is loaded by calling it from an `onload` handler on your `<script>` tag:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" async onload="init()"></script>

<script>
  function init() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //Some variable initialization 

      console.log("loaded");
    });
  }
</script>
```